# JavaFX - Watchdog-Timer in WebEngine.executeScript()

Tags: javafx, webview, thread-safety

In the following code:

```
public void onButtonClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) { 
    webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().
         stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable, Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue) {
       if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)
           webView.getEngine().executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);");
     }});
     webView.getEngine().loadContent("some content");
}
```

This code works just fine, the problem is that this line:

```
webView.getEngine().executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
```

is creating an infinite loop thread which does not terminate when the application terminates, hence producing this Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.destroy (ThreadGroup.java:778)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute (ExecJavaMojo.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

I know it is that line the one that produces this `Thread` with name `"Watchdog-Timer-1"`, because without executing that line, this `Thread` is never started and the app closes normally.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @kleopatra Post modified.